# How to set selected country isd code in spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner

- I don't know how to set the selected country isd code in
  spinner.Below I have posted the code what I have been tried so far:

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

 ArrayList<String> arrCode;
 ArrayList<String> arrCountry;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

        arrCode = new ArrayList<>();
        arrCountry = new ArrayList<>();

        arrCountry.add("US");
        arrCountry.add("KZ");
        arrCountry.add("EG");
        arrCountry.add("ZA");
        arrCountry.add("GR");

        arrCode.add("1");
        arrCode.add("7");
        arrCode.add("20");
        arrCode.add("27");
        arrCode.add("30");

  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_state = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrCountry);

        adapter_state.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        sp_mobile_code.setAdapter(adapter_state);
        sp_mobile_code.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    }

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                               long id) {

       int spinnerValue1 = sp_mobile_code.getSelectedItemPosition();

        String data = arrCode.get(spinnerValue1);

        Log.e("data", "" + data);


        sp_mobile_code.setPrompt(data);

     /*  sp_mobile_code.setSelection(position);*/


    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

- My issue is : I can't set the isd code in same spinner.If I have to
  set isd code in textview means it will be easy.But I have to set it
  in the spinner

**Edit:** spinner list showing correctly the country list.on clicking the country list, I have to show the isd code

Comment: let me tell u what i have understood. spinner list should show the country list. when you select some item in the spinner, now the spinner should show the arrCode instead of the selected country. correct?

Comment: @DineshBob spinner list showing correctly the country list.on clicking the country list, I have to show the isd code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Custom ArrayAdapter.

```
private static class CustomSpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
    {
         List<String> arrCodes;

        public CustomSpinnerAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<String> items, List<String> arrCodes) 
        {
            super(context, resource, items);
            this.arrCodes = new ArrayList<>();
            this.arrCodes = arrCodes;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            TextView view = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            view.setText(arrCodes.get(position));
            return view;
        }
    }
```

Check the position in the getView() and set text of your desire. Use this adapter for the Spinner

Comment: Can you elaborate more.I used this adapter.but I couldn't understood what's this textview will be used to display it in spinner

Comment: That is the TextView which is showed in the closed spinner.

Comment: I updated the answer. check it now. If im mistakenly understood, explain your question a bit more.

Comment: I am setting an adapter like this `sp_mobile_code.setAdapter(new CustomSpinnerAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                arrCode));  I am getting as a drop down as code and displaying as a code.I need to show dropdown as a country name.display only as a code

Comment: Check out this [pastie](http://pastie.org/private/gzs5brodw8wvsw0e92a) for adapter code.

Comment: sp_mobile_code.setAdapter(new CustomSpinnerAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrCountry, arrCode));

Comment: use this. there are 4 parameters.

Comment: 3rd parameter list will be used for drop down. 4th parameter list will be used to display text in closed spinner.

Comment: with your suggestion I used this [sample](http://mrbool.com/how-to-customize-spinner-in-android/28286) and added country as a parent view and code as a child view .then using hide and show a parent and child view in spiner click listener and adapter to get my expected result